# Finding Groupwise Maximum In Doctrine

Tags: doctrine

How do you find a groupwise maximum, or the row containing the maximum value, in Doctrine? In SQL, I would typically do this using a self join as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html).

While it's possible to set up a self relation in Doctrine, are there any better ways to do this?

Comment: Any reasons you don't want to use a self relation?

Comment: Two reasons: 1) It seems to violate the ORM model. That is, it doesn't make sense for the object to have a copy of itself. 2) I'm doing this query seldom so it doesn't seem worth it to add a relation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example of groupwise max:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
     ->select("txs.id, txs.amount, txs.valid_from")
     ->from("Tx txs")
     ->where("txs.amount = (SELECT MAX(transact.amount) FROM tx transact WHERE txs.id = transact.id)");
```

Example of row containing maximum:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
 ->select("txs.id, txs.amount, txs.valid_from")
 ->from("Tx txs")
 ->where("txs.id = (SELECT transact.id FROM tx transact WHERE transact.amount = (SELECT MAX(transactx.amount) FROM tx transactx))");
```

These are probably not the only ways (or most clean), but I just tested both and they work.

Answer (score 1):

This question is really old but it ranks highly on Google for "doctrine groupwise max" so I thought I'd add my solution.

In my case I had a parent Entity with many children and I wanted to select fields from the child with the highest ID.

```
$qb
    ->select('child1.field')
    ->from(Entity::class, 'entity')
    ->join('entity.children', 'child1')
    ->leftJoin('entity.children', 'child2', 'WITH', 'child1.entity=child2.entity AND child1.id<child2.id')
    ->where('child2.id IS NULL')
;
```